# How to catch unexpected response errors from Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using Volley to access some REST API. If a user enters a wrong password or anything else goes wrong I want to catch the exception. E.g.:

`E/Volley: [281] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401`

Can I catch this expception somehow?

Here is the LoginRequest:

```
public class LoginRequest  extends StringRequest{
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "URL";
    public static final String CLIENT_KEY= "SECRET";
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "ID";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("client_secret", CLIENT_KEY);
        params.put("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
        params.put("grant_type", "password");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

I added:

```
public class LoginRequest  extends StringRequest{
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "URL";
    public static final String CLIENT_KEY= "KEY";
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "ID";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener, **Response.ErrorListener errorListener**) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, **errorListener**);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("client_secret", CLIENT_KEY);
        params.put("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
        params.put("grant_type", "password");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

And added an Resonse.ErrorListener to my LoginActiviy and called the LoginRequest Method with the additional Parameter.

Comment: you need to send "Wrong Password" error from php to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom error listener which implements Volley's **Response.ErrorListener**, override onErrorResponse() method and get the response code.

### EDIT:

Actually you not need to create a custom ErrorListener since the default Volley's ErrorListener will be sufficient for your needs.

Just pass an instance of the Response.ErrorListener to your LoginRequest and do your logic in the onErrorResponse() method.

Comment: I added the code I use for the request, should I implement the method in there? Also how would it be returned to the LoginActivity?

Comment: Your 4th parameter in the super() is the error listener. Create a new error listener class which implements the Volley's Response.ErrorListener and when you create the LoginRequest pass it to it's constructor. Even you not need to create a custom ErrorListener since the default Volley's ErrorListener will be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

To catch all errors in volley, onErrorResponse is not reliable enough, I sometimes get null in onErrorResponse. I prefer to override **deliverError** like this:

```
 @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error){
        Log.e("deliverError", " here");
       int status = error.networkResponse.statusCode;

        switch (status)
        {
            case 401:

                break;
            case 307:
                break;
            ...
            default:

        }
    }
```